# Issues translating code from global positions to local positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is in Unity, using C#, its also for VR but I don't think the issue is expressly caused by being VR.

I have several cabinets in a kitchen scene, I am trying to write a script to get the cabinets doors a drawers to open following the player's hand. I had no issue writing the initial code to get both working wonderfully. being pretty new to Unity I thought that when I was writing a script that's going to be attached to a gameObject that it would be using the objects transform positions and rotations. instead, what I found was the perfectly executing code I had written only actually worked when the xyz axis and rotations matched the world axis and rotations. the drawers work only when the cabinet forward is the world forward and doors work only when the cabinet is perfectly level, no tilt to the y axis, but you can rotate around the y axis no problem.

here is the working code for the cabinet doors

```
public class DoorPull : XRBaseInteractable
{
    [Header("Required variables")]
    public GameObject door;
    public float openDegree = 90f;
    public float startingOpenDegree;
    public float handOffset = 90f;
    public bool hingeRight;

    private Vector3 closedRotation;
    private Vector3 openRotation;
    private IXRSelectInteractor hand;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    { 
        closedRotation = door.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;

        //sets the closed and max open positions.
        openRotation = closedRotation;
        if (hingeRight)
        {
            openRotation.y = closedRotation.y - openDegree;
        } 
        else
        {
            openRotation.y = closedRotation.y + openDegree;
        }

        //makes sure the door can't start further open than its max open position.
        if (startingOpenDegree > openDegree)
        {
            startingOpenDegree = openDegree;
        }

        //starts the door open at users starting open degree
        var startingOpenRotation = closedRotation;
        if (hingeRight)
        {
            startingOpenRotation.y -= startingOpenDegree; 
        }
        else
        {
            startingOpenRotation.y += startingOpenDegree;
        }
        door.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(startingOpenRotation);
    }

------------------------above this line works no matter the position or rotation of the cabinet, below this line must be aligned with world y axis to work------------------------------

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (interactorsSelecting.Count > 0)
        {
            hand = interactorsSelecting[0];
            Vector3 lookHere = hand.transform.position;
            lookHere.y = door.transform.position.y;
            door.transform.LookAt(lookHere, door.transform.up);
            var temp = door.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            
            if (hingeRight)
            {
                temp.y -= handOffset;
                //will have code to stop in open and closed positions
            }
            else
            {
                temp.y += handOffset;
                //will have code to stop in open and closed positions
            }

            door.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing all the "rotation" to "localRotation" as well as changing "Vector3 lookHere = hand.transform.position" to "Vector3 lookHere = door.transform.inverseTransformPoint(hand.transform.position)", with all those changes that I thought would make it translate everything into local space it does a lot of strange movements. def not behaving the same way it behaves as global. So clearly, I am doing something wrong in my translating from global space to local space.

Comment: All of your math should be in one of either World or Local coordinates (Local is usually easier the think about). ```LookAt``` is a rotation (or three) in its own right, so don't do both LookAt and set rotation.  See how that goes.

Comment: `LookAt` definitely requires values in **world space** as it operates in and results in a world space rotation. There is btw no need to directly apply it - you could go through [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) instead

Comment: and then of course if you store everything in **local** space within `Start` to your fields .. then you will also need to do the rest in **local** space

Comment: I would suggest a different approach: Instead of working with `Quaternion / EulerAngles` at all - all you really want and need for this is a **single angle**. You could simply always take the angle from closet forward -> touch point and simply use `localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);` with an additional clamping of that angle to e.g. `Mathf.Clamp(angle, 0, 90);`

Comment: "LookAt definitely requires values in world space" that would be why I've gotten close but still had issues, if that can only do world space then I was still doing math between local and world space. so there is no way to convert the lookAt into local space?

"everything in local space" yes, that's the part I'm having issue with, i had it all in global and working but translating to local I'm doing something wrong (probably the lookAt always being global, which I didn't realize)

"different approach" ill have to look more into that, thank you

Comment: so, if im reading how lookAt works properly, it makes the objects transform local forward point to the other object. is there a way to set local.up? door.transform.LookAt(lookHere, door.transform.up) the second argument returns world space up, I want a local up

Answer (score 0):

I got it working perfectly, feeling like its in your hand.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (interactorsSelecting.Count > 0)
    {
        hand = interactorsSelecting[0];
        float distanceToHand = transform.localPosition.z - door.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hand.transform.position).z;
        float doorChangeDegree = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(distanceToHand, distanceHingeToKnob);

        Vector3 directionToHand = Vector3.Normalize(transform.position - hand.transform.position);
        
        if (Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, directionToHand) > 0)
        {
            door.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(door.transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(closedRotation), doorChangeDegree);
        }
        else if (Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, directionToHand) < 0)
        {
            door.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(door.transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(openRotation), -doorChangeDegree);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: most of the time when you use rotateTowards you want it to move at a certain speed and you use time.deltaTime so it moves the distance per second rather than per frame, however this is for VR and you dont want the door moving slower than your hand so it calculates exactly where your hand is in every frame and moves the door into your hand each frame.

Comment: Thank you @derHugo for pointing me in the right direction of using angles